# How do I create a program that switches my default browser in macOS 10.15.6?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to create a program that switches between two browsers as default browser. For example, if my default browser is set to Brave Browser, the program will change it to Chrome and vice versa.
Unfortunately, I don't know apple script so I was hoping you guys could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

using your command line (via the terminal):

```
brew install defaultbrowser
```

and then (for example)

```
defaultbrowser chrome
```

Comment: Perfect. Tried a lot of AppleScripting solutions but none of them worked. But this was short, sweet and simple!, and worked like a charm!